# Why bigint changes to integer, and how to not make that happen in PostgreSQL on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

whenever I run `docker-compose up` (`db/schema.rb` changes as), many of my `bigint` types change to `integer` in PostgreSQL on Ruby on Rails. I later learnt that the repository's PostgreSQL version's 12, so I downgraded my PostgreSQL from 14 to 12, but it still doesn't work.

TL;DR: How can I not have `bigint` types change to `integer` in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post) I removed the "*PS. ...*" part, as well as all docker-related tags.

Comment: Well, you will need to show the schema.rb file otherwise this is impossible to answer.